# Is it possible to get boost::exception object from boost::exception_ptr?

Tags: boost, boost-exception

Is it possible to get boost::exception object from boost::exception_ptr? If yes How (in boost version 1.5x)?

Comment: Do you mean something like try { rethrow_exception(eptr); } catch(const exception &e) { /* you now have the original exception */ }?

Comment: No. I want to access the actual pointer or address of the object which boost::exception_ptr holding inside.

Comment: There is no official access to that.

Comment: If you know that the exception object derives from boost::exception, if you rethrow_exception(eptr) you can catch it as boost::exception &. The reference you'll get will refer to the actual object the exception_ptr holds.